# What constitutes "correcting minor mistakes" in a code example?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When are corrections to the code permissible as an edit?

For example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16486906) suggested edit. Here a variable name is changed from `isValid` to `isInvalid`.

This example doesn't change the functionality of the code, so is it acceptable?

I remember some time ago I noticed a typo in an answer which I described in the comments. The JS was targeting the html elements by class, but the markup had the class name as an id, not a class. Example:

JS

```
$(".foo").html(bar);
```

HTML

```
<div id= "foo"></div>
```

The answer as written does not work, but changing the class to id (as I believe was the author's intention) makes it work. I submitted it as a suggested edit and it was rejected.

This example corrects an apparent oversight and changes the code from broken to working.

I have seen this question [When should I make edits to code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) and it states
"To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages".

So, does fixing the class to id, as would be the obvious intent of the author, count as a "minor mistake" or is it changing the meaning of the code?

Comment: In the first case it's not changing the functionality but it's correctly naming the variable, so I would consider it an okay change as it actually improves the post without changing the output

Comment: So is semantic correction allowed but bugfixing not?

Comment: @mhatch I would say it depends on the scope of the variable, if it's a global or used elsewhere then no, but in this case it's not so it should be okay.

Comment: The FAQ discusses these cases specifically, specifically mentioning that it's appropriate to fix a typo or mistake in the code in order to keep it in line with what the author has stated it's supposed to do, so long as  you're confident that you're changing the code to what the author meant to type.

Comment: I usually just skip those suggested edits, but they come up pretty often and I would like to be clear on what the consensus is for handling them.

Comment: *as would be the obvious intent of the author* Did the author actually *say*  "This code is meant to change elements with a specific class" or was it an answer that didn't explain what it was doing but you inferred the intent from what code was there and/or the question post?

Comment: @Braiam Debatable. For instance consider stuff like `while(cond); {}` in c++. If someone comes to edit out the (unintentional) `;`, that might make the complete question useless.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ which is why we need experts reviewers, not the flying button mashing monkey we gave.

Comment: The marked duplicate is referenced in the question, and in fact, the question title quotes the marked duplicate. This is a follow-up question inspired by the mentioned question.

Comment: @mhatch And yet the marked duplicate answers your question.  You quoted a question from it's question, and ignored the fact that *it answers that exact issue* in the answer.